# What happens when you 'svn update' a local dir with unversioned files, which has been renamed on the server?

Tags: svn

My project dir is in SVN, but some files are per-user and not versioned. On one PC I've renamed this and committed successfully. But I'm worried updating the other PC will delete all those files... it will delete $old-dir-name rather than rename it and keep the contents.

Running SVN 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

`svn update` will bring your working copy to the state that the repository has, which means it will delete the files which are no longer in the repository and create the new ones which are now in the repository. but since you have renamed the files the content will not get lost, then it is in the renamed files. The history will not get lost too.

Here a test run with your scenario:

Rename the files in your working copy

```
Cmd-$> pwd
D:\Projects\C_C++\stackoverflow

Cmd-$> svn rename test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update.c \
         test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update_renamed.c
A         test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update_renamed.c
D         test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update.c
```

svn says it will delete the old file and add the the new file

No commit the working copy

```
Cmd-$> svn ci -m "renamed"
Deleting       test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update.c
Adding         test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update_renamed.c

Committed revision 718.
```

svn deletes the old file in the repository and adds the the new file to it. The changes are commit with a certain revision.

Now Update you update the other working copy (the step at which you are standing now)

```
Cmd-$> pwd
D:\Projects\svn_test

Cmd-$> svn update so
Updating 'so':
D    so\test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update.c
A    so\test_svn_rename_update\test_svn_rename_update_renamed.c
Updated to revision 718.
```

svn says it has update the working copy to a certain revision and it has delete one file and added another, in the case of renaming it is the same file but has now another name.

You shouldn't be worried about loosing any content, you could even delete the working copy from the second pc (using the filesystem NOT svn delete!!!) and check it out again. This will have the same effect.

If you are still worried, just zip the other working copy by side and do a `svn update` and see what happens!